# How to flip X and Y axes in Excel scatter chart with more than one series

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I don't understand how to perform a simple 90 degree axis manipulation in Excel.

Here is my data:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Y  ║  X1  ║  X2   ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 0.00 ║ -1.00 ║
║  2 ║ 0.50 ║ 0.00  ║
║  3 ║ 0.67 ║ 0.33  ║
║  4 ║ 0.75 ║ 0.50  ║
║  5 ║ 0.80 ║ 0.60  ║
║  6 ║ 0.83 ║ 0.67  ║
║  7 ║ 0.86 ║ 0.71  ║
║  8 ║ 0.88 ║ 0.75  ║
║  9 ║ 0.89 ║ 0.78  ║
║ 10 ║ 0.90 ║ 0.80  ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

And here is what the default scatter looks like:

[Excel default - please click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTbjb.png)

Excel has correctly picked up my two series (X1 and X2) but I want to flip the X and Y axes. The result should look like this:

[Excel edited - please click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZSPZ.png)

I had to create that by manually editing the X and Y values for each series within Excel's Select Data... dialogue. That's fine for one or two series, but what if I want to plot 100s of series? I can't possibly reconfigure them all manually. So how do I format my data so that Excel treats the first col as Y values, and each subsequent col as the corresponding X value of each new series? Thanks

Comment: See my answer in the linked duplicate post, which is a VBA routine to plot scatter charts from data arranged like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this in excel.

Using vba a macro like this would work.  This will swap all the series in the active chart.  No error checking or anything included.

```
Sub swap()
Dim seriesformula() As String

For Each mySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    seriesformula() = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")
    mySeries.Formula = seriesformula(0) & "," & seriesformula(2) & "," & seriesformula(1) & "," & seriesformula(3)
Next

End Sub
```